# Laravel 5.7 email verification throws 403

Tags: laravel, email-verification, laravel-5.7

I implemented email verification in a Laravel 5.7 project I'm working on. I get the email, but whenever I click on the confirm button or even the url provided in the email, I get a 403 forbidden error.

I have searched for several solutions, but haven't been able to find one to this problem. The only reasonable pointers to this error is this github issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25716 which has been merged and closed by Taylor Otwell by still this problem persists.

Here's the email I get: [image] 
Here's the error it throws when I click on the button or the actionUrl at the email footer:[image] and here's the url shown when the 403 page is displayed https://www.mywebsite.com/email/verify/1?expires=1540140119&signature=fd7dc72b05da6f387b2f52a27bceee533b2256436f211930c1319c7a544067da

Please help me. Thank you

Edits: This problem occurs only in production app. On local, this email verification works but throws 403 on production(live) server. My email service is mailgun, and I can access every other email contents relating to the app except completing email verification.
I need help please. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: When you `php artisan route:list`, do you get the following middelware for the `verification.verify` route name: `web,auth,signed,throttle:6,1`?

Comment: Yes, I get it. I just checked again to confirm

Comment: Hey @Ehi, did you set your `APP_URL` in your `.env` file?

Comment: For future me, the problem was that I was already logged in with another account in Chrome when I tried to verify the email of a new account. Logging out first account (or using another browser for the second account) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 15):

One of the reasons that was in my case can be that you are already logged in with a normal verified user, and you have clicked on the verification email link. In that case it will shoot 403 . Which is not normal in my opinion, but whatever.

Comment: For your deleted [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76844/hash-two-strings-independent-from-the-sequence). Consider a=1, b =11

Answer (score 8):

For me because manually create verification route. which in laravel 6.x or 7.x The route path for verifying emails has changed. from `/email/verify/{id}` to `/email/verify/{id}/{hash}` This probably only happens because I use the rules manually, and not `Auth::routes(['verify' => true])`
for more information laravel upgrade guide [upgrade#email-verification-route-change](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#email-verification-route-change)

Answer (score 3):

This typically occurs if your application is running behind some proxies and probably doesn't handle SSL termination itself.

The solution is to add

`protected $proxies = '*';`

to the `TrustProxies` middleware.

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hitting-403-page-when-clicking-verify-link-in-email-using-new-laravel-verification-57?page=1

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, this often happens when you have your laravel app running behind a proxy (apache, nginx etc.) We therefore end up replacing laravel's default 'signed' middleware with our own middleware that checks for https:// links. This StackOverFlow answer here was able to fix this problem for me:

[Signed route for email verification does not pass signature validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525958/signed-route-for-email-verification-does-not-pass-signature-validation)

Answer (score 0):

To use Laravel email verification you must first add the proper routes.

If you take a look at `Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` you'll see that by default the verify route is disabled.

```
if($options['verify'] ?? false) 
{
    $this->emailVerification();
}
```

To enable your verification routes add the following to your `web.php`

```
Auth::routes(['verify'=>true]);
```

Then run

```
php artisan route:list
```

to make sure that it's working.

Comment: `Auth::routes(['verify'=>true]);` is already added to my web.php file, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: i check my projects and see same error. in auth/verifyController.php "singed middleware" check for signature . if you add some thing to your url this will fail .in my case when disable and enable this middleware problem resolved!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the verify method inside the VerifiesEmails trait,
there they have:

```
if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($request->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {
    throw new AuthorizationException;
}
```

I have dumped this variable `$request->route('hash')` and it was null, so I overrided it in the VerificationController:

```
    /**
 * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
 */
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('id'), (string) $request->user()->getKey())) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->query('hash'), sha1($request->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

And now it works!

Comment: this worked for me to, any idea whats causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was my APP_URL had a protocol of **http** and when I clicked on the verification link NGINX automatically redirected the url from http to **https** that's why the signature validation failed. I updated the APP_URL to have a protocol of **https** and that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience with this problem was that I set `MAIL_DRIVER` to `log` in the `.env` file, and Laravel escaped special characters (such as &) when it stored the activation link in the log.

So NEVER use the `log` for `MAIL_DRIVER` when you have verification email.
(my Laravel version was 5.8).