# Laravel 7 verify email adress invalid signature

Tags: php, laravel, email

After clicking verify email address button in the email, I got **403** invalid signature. 
I'm using shared hosting

I have read these

1. [Laravel 5.7 email verification throws 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917152/laravel-5-7-email-verification-throws-403)
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/403-invalid-signature-every-time-i-try-to-verify-email-in-laravel-57
3. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/email-verification-403-invalid-signature

but still can't solve my problem

Comment: try to follow the solutions from git issues https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26930

Comment: i've tried it, but still doesn't solve anything

Comment: have you done `php artisan config:cache` then re-run your apps after you change them?

Comment: yes i've done it

Comment: @Caroline Any solution ??

Comment: I know its an old one! But if someone comes across here like me, thought it might help. The main problem seems to be the cache! and compiled routes and views. After searching for solutions everywhere about what I did wrong. Just ran the following commands: `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`  followed by `php artisan route:clear` and lastly `php artisan view:clear`. Restarted my server and Voila!  it started working.

Answer (score 2):

Same happen to me, but only in production while using `FORCE_HTTPS` to set all my routes to `https`,

if I disable `Force_https` it works, but my routes go back to `https`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the verification link is already expired.

Referring to UrlGenerator.php,

```
public function hasValidSignature(Request $request, $absolute = true)
{
    return $this->hasCorrectSignature($request, $absolute)
        && $this->signatureHasNotExpired($request);
}
```